# How do I keep the original shape of the destination surface when blitting?

Tags: graphics, sdl, blit

Take a look at the screenshot below. There are three thin SDL 2.0 surfaces displayed, all more or less rectangular.

[Blitting image 1 onto image 2 - get image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EVQh.png)

The first surface (the brownish paper one) is **Image 1**
The white one below it with the two corners missing is **Image 2**

I would like to perform a SDL_BlitSurface so that Image 1 is blitted onto Image 2, but with the shape of Image 2 (in other words, the end result should look like brown paper, but have two of its corners missing.

To do this, I try:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(Image1, NULL, Image2, NULL);
```

But instead of the desired result, I get the third surface in the picture (Image 3), which is the same as Image 1

---

UPDATE

---

So on keltar's advice, I've replaced my blit function call with a call to a bespoke function that I hope is copying the alpha channel for each pixel from Image 1 to Image 2

```
copy_alpha(Image1, Image2);
```

```
void IMAGETOOL::copy_alpha(SDL_Surface * src, SDL_Surface * dst)
{
    int w = src->w,
        h = src->h;

    Uint32 opixel, npixel;
    Uint8 r, g, b, a;

    if (SDL_MUSTLOCK(src)) SDL_LockSurface(src);
    if (SDL_MUSTLOCK(dst)) SDL_LockSurface(dst);

    Uint8 srcAlpha = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            opixel = get_pixel(src, x, y);
            SDL_GetRGBA(opixel, src->format, &r, &g, &b, &a);
            srcAlpha = a;
            opixel = get_pixel(dst, x, y);
            SDL_GetRGBA(opixel, dst->format, &r, &g, &b, &a);
            a = srcAlpha;
            npixel = SDL_MapRGBA(dst->format, r, g, b, a);
            put_pixel(dst, x, y, npixel);
        }

    if (SDL_MUSTLOCK(src)) SDL_UnlockSurface(src);
    if (SDL_MUSTLOCK(dst)) SDL_UnlockSurface(dst);
}
```

The resulting surface has changed. but not in the way I had hoped.

[Copying alpha from image 1 to image 2 - get image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiLYm.png)

Not sure what to make of this - any ideas?

Comment: Is third image relevant to question in any bit? What resulting image you want to get? Should it have alpha channel? https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface describes how blitting works for each format combination. Not sure I get your intention, but sounds like you just want to copy alpha channel from one image to another?

Comment: I want the final image to have the look of the first image, but have the shape of the second image. Instead I get the third image - looks right, but wrong shape.

Comment: Okay but is resulting image supposed to have alpha channel? Does second image have it? If both are correct, then you just want to copy alpha and nothing more. I don't think there is a blit function to do that, but can quite easily be done via loop.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. The original surfaces were created from .png images, so they probably have alpha channel. I will investigate further and post back. It would be strange if SDL 1.2 could do this via blit, but 2.0 required a bespoke function. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. In my last update, I was trying to copy alpha from Image 1 to Image 2 - wrong way round!

But when I use the same function to copy alpha from image 2 to Image 1 (I'm guessing that is what keltar meant for me to do).

```
copy_alpha(Image2, Image1);
```

the modified Image 1 gives the desired result.

[Copying alpha from image 2 to image 1 - get image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwpfM.png)

Thanks for your help keltar!